# grails spring security post authentication

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I use spring security core plugin. I want to put an object in session just after user has logged in. What I've discovered so far is that there is `grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController` in the plugin. And it has method which is called `ajaxSuccess` which seems to be invoked just after successfull authentication. So I decided to create another LoginController which extends default one and overrides this method:

```
@Secured('permitAll')
class LoginController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController {


    def ajaxSuccess() {
        session['somevproperty'] = someValue 
        super.ajaxSuccess()
    }

}
```

but debugging shows that this method is never invoked. What is going wrong? May there is another way to do what I want? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring security has it own event listeners. I prefer you use that.

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/events.html

Sample code from above link for success login.

```
package com.foo.bar

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener  
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event. AuthenticationSuccessEvent

class MySecurityEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

      void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) { 
      // handle the event
      } 
}
```